# JavaScript check if object is array with specific values

Tags: javascript

I want to check an object which is always an array. One important case is where it is an array equivalent to `foo` below. But it could contain any number of integers. I need to evaluate the specific case in an `if` statement. However, I find the behavior confusing:

```
let foo = [0]

foo === [0] // false
foo == [0] // false
foo === 0 // false
foo == 0 // true
```

How can I check whether `foo` is the exact array of `[0]`?

Thanks!

Edit: Thanks for your comments. Not sure if this really is a duplicate. In any case, thanks for the solutions. I went for `if (foo instanceof Array && foo.length == 1 && foo[0] === 0)`.

Comment: `if (foo instanceof Array && foo.length == 1 && foo[0] === 0)`

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown would also return true for `[0,1]`.

Comment: @JaredSmith in that case the `length` would be `2`.

Comment: `JSON.stringify(foo) === JSON.stringify(bar)` or `foo.filter((el, index) => el === bar[index]).length === foo.length`

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown that's what I get for looking at stuff on my phone. Sorry!

Comment: @JaredSmith hahaha no problem!!